# C# - How to save a single Excel WorkSheet in the current WorkBook?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have seen some other existing questions about saving a single worksheet but the are regarding saving a worksheet in a new workbook (by copying it to the new workbook and then saving it. What I need is to save just one specific worksheet within the existing workbook, is to not possible?

Thank you!

Comment: WorkSheet cannot exist without a WorkBook as far as I know. So the way to do it is to copy to the new workbook as suggested in other questions

Answer (score 1):

### No

If you check the [list of Microsoft Office file specifications](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd797428.aspx), none of them accommodate the storage of a single worksheet.  So the answer to your question is no.

### Yes

On the other hand, when you save as a [non-Excel type such as CSV or TXT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1), Excel will only save the current sheet.  So if you're OK with storing the worksheet in a non-native format, with possible data loss, then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read worksheets programmatically then this might help you.

You can programmatically read each sheet in a workbook and save a particular sheet or a range of cells inside the sheet in the same workbook or as new sheet or as .txt,.csv and many other formats.. Use [ByteScout](https://bytescout.com/products/developer/spreadsheetsdk/bytescoutspreadsheetsdk.html) and read about the documentation from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/bytescout.com/files/help/BytescoutSpreadsheetSDK/index.html). There are many examples provided by them. Please let us know if you are facing any problem.